# Hide 3-dots menu in Teams mobile custom app (spfx)

Tags: mobile, microsoft-teams, web-parts, spfx, microsoft-teams-js

I'd like to hide the "..." menu in a custom app (spfx-webpart), which is displayed, when the tab is opened in the teams mobile app:

Screenshot showing the menu I like to hide

[image: 1]

Is this possible?

I tried to find some docs from Microsoft and googled a lot, but I did not found a solution

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will let you know once we get any updates from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide 3-dots menu in Teams mobile custom app.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)